# x2go connect to Manjaro VM with awesome window manager

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-control, awesome-wm

I would like to connect with a x2go client to a VM running Manjaro with Awesome as window manager (x2go server).

Unfortunately, the connection does not start. The x2go client opens showing a black window using "startx" as "Command".

So, which is the correct "Session Type" to be chosen in x2go client? If "Custom desktop" has to be chosen, how about the "Command"?

Information:

OS: Manjaro Linux 17.1.12

VMware Player: 12.5.9

x2go client version: 4.1.2.1-3

x2go client server: 4.1.0.3-1

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- Ensure that you are not logged in locally with the same user you use in x2go client, see [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/allow-a-local-session-and-a-remote-x2go-session-concurrently/68959)
- "Command" is **awesome**, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1371000/awesome-window-manager-does-not-start)

Hope this helps other x2go users